# Track how many times a user clicks a button and later display it with React and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I making a fact generator website and I have a generate button on my homepage, when a user is logged in I want to track how many times they have clicked the button and later display it on their homepage. I am very new to React and Firebase so if any additional information is needed please inform me.

My app.js (has firebase functions & generate button)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import BackGround from "./components/BG";
import FactGen from "./components/FactGen";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./components/About";
import NoMatchPage from "./components/NoMatchPage";
import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import fire from "./components/fire";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState("");
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState("");
  const [hasAccount, setHasAccount] = useState(false);

  const clearInputs = () => {
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
  };

  const clearErrors = () => {
    setEmailError("");
    setPasswordError("");
  };

  const handleLogin = () => {
    clearErrors();
    fire
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((err) => {
        switch (err.code) {
          case "auth/invalid-email":
          case "auth/user-disabled":
          case "auth/user-not-found":
            setEmailError(err.message);
            break;
          case "auth/wrong-password":
            setPasswordError(err.message);
            break;
        }
      });
  };

  const handleSignup = () => {
    clearErrors();
    fire
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((err) => {
        switch (err.code) {
          case "auth/email-already-in-use":
          case "auth/invalid-email":
            setEmailError(err.message);
            break;
          case "auth/weak-password":
            setPasswordError(err.message);
            break;
        }
      });
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    fire.auth().signOut();
  };

  const authListener = () => {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        clearInputs();
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser("");
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    authListener();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <BackGround />
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          {/* <Route path="/Userconnections" component={Userconnections} /> */}
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route
            path="/Auth"
            render={(props) => (
              <Login
                email={email}
                setEmail={setEmail}
                password={password}
                setPassword={setPassword}
                handleLogin={handleLogin}
                hasAccount={hasAccount}
                setHasAccount={setHasAccount}
                emailError={emailError}
                passwordError={passwordError}
                user={user}
                handleSignup={handleSignup}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/dashboard"
            render={(props) => (
              <Dashboard handleLogout={handleLogout} user={user} />
            )}
          />
          <Route component={NoMatchPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(0);
  const refresher = () => {
    setRefresh(refresh + 1);
    console.log(refresh);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FactGen key={refresh} />
      <center>
        <button className="generate-button" onClick={refresher}>
          Generate
        </button>
      </center>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My dashboard.js (Want it to display the value where it says 100 on line 14 right now)

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const Dashboard = ({ handleLogout, user }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  function homeRedirect() {
    history.push("/");
  }
  return (
    <Router>
      {user ? null : homeRedirect()}
      <div>
        <h1 className="welcome-text">Welcome, User</h1>
        <h1 className="page-header">You have generated 100 Facts!</h1>
        <center>
          <button className="logout-button" onClick={handleLogout}>
            Logout
          </button>
        </center>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a state variable on the parent component and passing the callback to the child:

```
    // Parent.js :
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    ...
    return (
    ...
      <ChildComponent setCounter={setCounter} counter={counter} />
      <p> You have clicked the button {counter} times </p> 
    ...
    )
```

Then, since you pass the callback, you can do this in your ChildComponenet

```
//Child.js
const Child = (props) => {
  const { setCounter, counter } = props

  return (
   ...
   <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}> Counter Button </button>
   ...
  )
}
```

Comment: But how can I make it user-specific?

Comment: That is a whole another question. You need a user object, that will be passed to the parent component. User object will have a field to store button clicked. You will need to update the user object. This is just one way, there are many others